# Apostrophs in Locales Riddle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Rails 3 app contains a locale like the following one (shortened for readability):

```
fr:
  mailer:
    apology: "... pour l'utilisation de ..."
```

This locale string is used in a text mail template, say whatever.text.erb:

```
<%= t(:'mailer.apology') %>
```

The mail created, however, replaces the apostrophe with it's HTML entity:

```
... pour l&#x27;utilisation de ...
```

I couldn't find any helpful option for `I18n#translate`, anybody know a solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing this is because Rails's template renderer escapes content automatically. Have you tried marking the output as html safe? e.g.

```
<%= t('mailer.apology').html_safe %>
```

Assuming you are not expecting dangerous content in your locale ;)

Comment: In that case I'm not sure. If you try in console (`I18n.t('mailer.apology')`) do you also get the escaped output?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself - it's a bug:
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/6943